# Deploying ASP.NET 5 in VSO to azure fails with parse error

Tags: azure, msbuild, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I am following the steps outlined in the [MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5) with a new ASP.NET 5 project using Visual Studio 2015.

I'm hitting an error on parsing the `.xproj` file specified in the Build Visual Studio step. The errors from the log file are below. I've verified the options to allow NuGet to download missing packages and also to check during builds are checked.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this would be appreciated.

> 2016-02-07T00:17:40.4869527Z Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.19\VSBuild.ps1
>
> 2016-02-07T00:17:41.0497025Z C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe restore "C:\a\1\s\TakeMeds\src\TakeMeds\TakeMeds.xproj" -NonInteractive
>
> 2016-02-07T00:17:45.2608365Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
>
> 2016-02-07T00:17:45.5323001Z ##[error]Error parsing solution file at C:\a\1\s\TakeMeds\src\TakeMeds\TakeMeds.xproj: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> 2016-02-07T00:17:45.5403287Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe

Comment: Is there more error message?

Comment: Unfortunately, no further error messages. Happy to add flags for more verbose output...would need some pointers though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to removed nuget.targets and nuget.exe files from .nuget folder in your solution and change all csproj files by following [this](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore) blog.

Comment: Your note helped me to understand MSBuild better. For now, I've not modified the script, but only removed the request on the Visual Studio Build so NuGet pacakges are not restored. Thanks!